# SpringBoot WebFlux: Parsing Parallel WebClient Requests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am making parallel rest calls to an API with the spring webclient.
The response looks like this

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Test A"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Test B",
        }

    ]
  }
}
```

POJOs:

```
public class ProductResponse {
    private Products d;
}

public class Products {
    private List<ProductModel> results;
}

public class Product {
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

API Call:

```
public Flux<ProductsResponse> getProducts(final List<String> pages) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(pages)
            .flatMap(page -> webClient.get().uri("SOMEURL?page={page}", page)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)                        
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(ProductsResponse.class))
            .log()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
}
```

Getting the products

```
Flux<ProductsResponse> productList = getProductList(pages);
List<ProductsResponse> productsResponse = productList.collectList().block();
for (ProductsResponse response : productsResponse) {
    for (ProductModel product: response.getD().getResults()) {
        System.out.println(product.getProductId());
    }
}
```

This is also working but is there a way to return directly `Flux<Product>` or is it better to return `Mono<List<Product>>`?

(the next step would be to save the products in a database)

Comment: Is wrong to block a flux and is not good to collect it in a list, you should manage it as flux.
return flux save in db as flux and not collect or block it.

Comment: how would I return `Flux<Product>`?

Comment: can you explain a bit more what do you want to do with your Flux<Product> ?

Comment: how you convert from ProductsResponse list to Products

Answer (score 0):

Please try it as below:

```
        Flux<Product> productFlux = Flux.fromIterable(pages)
            .flatMap(page -> client.get().uri("SOMEURL?page={page}", page)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(ProductResponse.class)
                    .map(productResponse -> productResponse.d.results)
                    .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable))
            .log()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
```

Answer (score 0):

You will optimally use the `ReactiveCrudRepository` interface for persisting data, where you can persist without using `block()`.

`public interface ProductRepository extends R2dbcRepository<Product> {}`

You can use both approaches:

1. with the raw flux:`getProductList(pages).flatMap(productRepository::save);`
2. with collectList: `getProductList(pages).collectList().flatMap(productRepository::saveAll);`

I would go for the second approach, as it translates to one SQL statement with multiple inserts/updates.